# nexus/maven deploy to old IP of nexus server

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins, nexus

I use AWS EC2 instances for RHEL7 for jenkins master and installed sonarqube, nexus, maven.. on it. After the installation and configuration I ran few jobs on jenkins everything seems good, later my server seemed to hang so I had to stop and start it. This made the IP of RHEL server change.

Now when I'm trying to run a job that does maven deploy... sonarqube tried to access old server IP and I changed in jenkins>global configuration. So sonarqube works fine now. But after that maven is trying to access my old server IP&port of nexus. I couldn't figure it out where I can modify.

Ps: the job I run is from a git repository that doesn't belong  to me and I didn't clone it, so lets consider there is no access to pom.xml file of that project.

I followed this for nexus installation [1] https://devopscube.com/how-to-install-latest-sonatype-nexus-3-on-linux/
Git project URL: https://github.com/vemular1/dev-maxo-demo/

the error I got when deploying it, maven deployment repo is targeting for old IP.

```
 --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ maxotech ---
[INFO] Installing /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy/target/maxotech-1.4.jar to /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/maxo/maxotech/1.4/maxotech-1.4.jar
[INFO] Installing /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/deploy/pom.xml to /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/maxo/maxotech/1.4/maxotech-1.4.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ maxotech ---
Uploading to deploymentRepo: http://35.193.152.132:8081/repository/maven-releases/com/maxo/maxotech/1.4/maxotech-1.4.jar
Uploading to deploymentRepo: http://35.193.152.132:8081/repository/maven-releases/com/maxo/maxotech/1.4/maxotech-1.4.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 04:20 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-20T13:47:39Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project maxotech: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.maxo:maxotech:jar:1.4 from/to deploymentRepo (http://35.193.152.132:8081/repository/maven-releases/): Connect to 35.193.152.132:8081 [/35.193.152.132] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I'm new to stackoverflow, please let me know if I didn't post according to format.

Comment: Do you have your nexus server repo at `35.193.152.132` ?

Comment: no I don't, I stopped and restarted my EC2 instance and server IP has changed.
I couldn't figure out where I can update the nexus server IP for this job to run. 
I don't have a clone of Git repo so I can't update POM.xml file. But it somehow got my old IP.

Comment: Are you able to access the nexus repo over the public IP of your EC2 instance that hosts nexus repo. I am not sure if you are aware of the public and private IP of an EC2 instance.

Comment: Yes I'm able  to access nexus with public IP of EC2. I didn't configure my instance with elastic IP so Public IP keeps changing whenever I stop and start EC2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your **pom.xml** with the newly assigned IP from your EC2 instance after the restart and do a refresh for your maven project.

`mvn clean install -U`

Also, as you rightly mentioned the IP changes after the restart, you may need to have an elastic IP for your instance so that you don't have to perform this change every time.

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>deploymentRepo</id>
        <name>Internal Releases</name>
        <url>http://35.193.152.132:8081/repository/maven-releases/</url>
    </repository>

    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>deploymentRepo</id>
        <name>Internal Releases</name>
        <url>http://35.193.152.132:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>

</distributionManagement>
```

Comment: could you don't mind and give a little information in which pom.xml?
because I didn't clone the project (if you are mentioning about project pom.xml)
I neither have this project in my workspace of jenkins.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: I meant pom.xml of the project that you are trying to build via jenkins job. AFAiIK Jenkins willjust runs the maven build and doesn’t bother about the nexus configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, that was my bad asking above question. That job was running on my slave all the time and I'm checking for that project workspace folder on master. You are Awesome. Thank you.